# when i click , i need to reverse name on ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using orderby filter in angularjs , When i click the button i need to sort the data , Without clicking it should not display sorting order.

```
<tr ng-repeat="tools in toolsfilter | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort ">
    <td style="color:forestgreen;" ng-if="tools.approved == true"> Approved </td>
    <td style="color:#a94442" ng-if="tools.approved == false"> Rejected </td>
    <td style="color:#aba8a8" ng-if="tools.approved == null"> Pending approval </td>
</tr>
```

In above code by default it is displaying sorted order  . 
when i click button(orderByField) then it should sort other wise it should be as same as received data from server side  .

```
<tr>
    <th ng-click="orderByField='name'; reverseSort = !reverseSort" width="30%">
        Tool name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'name'">
     <span ng-show="!reverseSort">&Delta;</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">&nabla;</span>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: what is the value of `orderByField` by default ?

Comment: we are setting $scope.orderByField = 'name';

Answer (score 0):

By default don't set any value for `orderByField`, keep it undefined or null, that way your content won't get ordered on start, it will get ordered on click only.

```
 $scope.orderByField = '';
```

OR

```
 $scope.orderByField = null;
```

OR

```
 $scope.orderByField;
```